# Why does this look like spam?

Tags: support, spam-detection

The post to superuser.com is here: https://pastebin.com/FVKFpbmd. I removed the first part, and you can also let me know if it is against something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tweaked the spam filter on Super User a bit, and your post should go through it fine now.

Having said that, your first paragraph is best left out. I understand that you want a speedy solution to your specific problem, but that's not really how Stack Exchange works. Our goal is to build up a knowledge base of questions and answers. If you want to hire someone to build software for you, there are other, better sites out there.

Comment: Yes, remove the first part, or it will be removed by the community.  We will either know the answer and it will be submitted for everyone or we won't.  Private help won't happen.  So providing your email won't result in an answer.  Vulgarities should also be removed.  Your Commentary should also be removed.  Just ask the question, provide what you have done, what the problem is, and specifically indicate your question

Comment: as mentioned the first part is because lots of people have no idea, i'll remove it anyway

Comment: @Ramhound sorry non-native English speaker, vulgarities? Could I have an example?

Comment: @KristoferVesi *shit* and *fucked up* are vulgarities.

Comment: **"I had a issue with the touchpad, since Windows 10 ****** everything up."** - I removed the word, but the word I removed, is considered to be vulgar.  Vulgar words have no business being in a question.  By removing the commentary you solve this problem.  The sentence I quoted is commentary, it serves no purpose, it doesn't actually tell us anything helpful.

Comment: I hope you didn't cause "OFFER 5$ PAYPAL" to go through the filter, even if not spam, it's surely off topic and such "offers" should be deleted all over Stack Exchange.